# Theme is not changing in homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I'm pretty new to Magento, I installed a theme on my local Magento shop, and changed every field in the **system** > **configuration** > **design** > **themes** to my_template_name and cleared the cache.

All of my pages' theme has been changed, but my homepage still has the default theme of Magento(the theme before I install the new one), what should I do ?

[image]

Comment: What's your design folder/theme structure ? Have you checked for any mistakes there ?

Comment: please check is your new theme is under the rwd folder or else other place.please let me know.or can you print the folder structure here

Comment: could you be more specific ? I know nothing about rwd or theme structure

Comment: just go to the app/design/frontend/ and what are the folders here

Comment: @PradeepSanku - look at the image I added in the Question

Comment: paste the image of the app/design/frontend/default/

Comment: @PradeepSanku - look at the update

Comment: so i think your theme is f001

Comment: No, its `magento_absolute_theme_free`, and I installed it with magento connect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If uploaded theme is f001 and your setting should be like as follows

[image]

Comment: No, its magento_absolute_theme_free, and I installed it with Magento connect.

Comment: try this which i gave you

Comment: it works, but not on the homepage, I did exactly what you said

Comment: please on the template hint and check the home page from where it is rendering

Comment: I did not understand your comment, sorry, can you rephrase it ?

Comment: go to the system > Configiuration > in the left side to you will see the Current Configuration Scope from the that drop down select Default Store View and go to the down their you will see the Developer click on that then Under Debug please select Template Path Hints and Add Block Names to Hints to yes and save and edit and refresh home page

Comment: now you can see the file name from where it is coming

Comment: there are many addresses in the page (about 20), which one is important?

Comment: and what should I do next?

Comment: and what should I do next?

Comment: check how you can enable template hints

Comment: I enabled it, I see the path, many path in my homepage is displaying, I just dont know what to do

Comment: I think my home page is using `rwd/default` path